# HTML5 : How to get native player Prev and Next button event in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, html

I am playing video in iOS using html5 video player. I am using following code for that :

```
   var player = $('#videoPlayer');
   player.attr('src',video.file_url);
   player.play();
```

It is working fine and it is playing on native video player . But the problem comes when I tried to play the videos sequentially . I want the **next** and **previous**  button event from native iOS player . Right now I can detect the next button event by attaching the **onend** event listener to the video . But the problem is with the **Prev** button click I have tried many events but unfortunately could not get that **prev** button click . Is there any way to get that button event ?

Comment: what markup gives you prev and next buttons?

Comment: @dandavis: I am not sure what do you want to know ?

Comment: It is unclear whether you're referring to WebKit or using Safari on a iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

Can not do as of (Oct.14) the player is native iOS and no events are passed to webview because this button is for navigating the the devices tracklist.